# how to convert .cdr file to .jpg image or .svg

Tags: php

How to convert the .cdr file to image (.jpg, .png) or .svg

I have converted the .svg file to .jpg, .png by using imageMagick, but imageMagick not getting to .cdr convert.

How to use UniConvertor in php for converting .cdr files to .svg format.

Comment: `ImageMagick` does not support the `.cdr` format.But Recent versions of ImageMagick support CRD with the help of the uniconvertor delegate program.

Comment: Then how to covert the files as images. ???

Comment: No native solution in PHP for converting CDR. I  Latest Version of ImageMagic does this with help of uniConverter https://sourceforge.net/projects/uniconvertor/

Comment: Thanks Kiran and yahoo. I searched, for convert .cdr to .svg UniConvertor will help. But I don't know how to use this in php, kindly help

Comment: If you can write shell commands from your PHP< use exce() or system() to execute the commands for imageMagick

Comment: Or convert CDR to PDF using Uniconvert and then to PNG using JPG `Step 1.
uniconvertor FILE.cdr FILE.pdf

Step 2.a Converting PDF to PNG using ImageMagick
convert -density 300 FILE.pdf FILE.png`

Comment: Thank you so much.. But I don't know about UniCovertor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to use UniConvertor in php for converting .cdr files to .svg format.

UniConvertor is a command line program. Using PHP, you can call it using `system()` or `exec()` like the following:

```
system('uniconvertor drawing.cdr drawing.svg');
```

The general CLI command syntax is:

```
$ uniconvertor [input file] [output file]
```

This syntax is covered in the [Ubuntu uniconvertor docs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/uniconvertor.1.html).

To install UniConvertor, you can get the files from the [project download page](http://sk1project.org/modules.php?name=Products&product=uniconvertor&op=download) for multiple OSes and from [Ubuntu.com](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/uniconvertor.1.html) for Unbuntu specifically.

Additional installation instructions for Ubuntu are available here: [How to get Uniconvertor 1.1.5](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1865589).

Comment: Kindly tell how to install the uniconvertor. I have downloaded the package.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I've added some download and instruction links above.

Comment: Thank you Grokify, I will check and let you know

Comment: Grokify, successfully installed uniconvertor, its working fine in command prompt, but not working from php code, kindly help

Comment: To execute an external program like unicovertor from PHP, you'll need to use a command like [system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) and [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). See those linked PHP Manual pages on how to ensure these are configured.

Comment: Ya thanks a lot.. Its working fine now, folder permission I missed.